# How to rotate folium CustomIcon?

Tags: leaflet, geospatial, folium

I have dataframe, it have name,latitudedes,longitudes and heading.

heading value will between 0 and 360. according to the angle we need to rotate.

I printed my dataframe items inside folium map in following way.

```
df_counters = pd.DataFrame({'Name': names,'latitude':latitudedes,'longitude':longitudes ,'heading':headings})
locations = df_counters[['latitude','longitude']]
locationlist = locations.values.tolist()
print(locationlist)

map = folium.Map(location=[1.3521,103.8198],zoom_start=11.5)

for point in range(0, len(locationlist)):
    pushpin = folium.features.CustomIcon('/ship_icon.png', icon_size=(15,15))
    folium.Marker(locationlist[point],icon=pushpin, popup=df_counters['Name'][point]).add_to(map)
map
```

can i know how to rotate this folim custom item according to the heading value.

Comment: The angle can be set on the normal icon, but it seems that the angle cannot be set on the unique icon. I referred to [this](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/latest/user_guide/ui_elements/icons.html#Custom-icon). So it may be necessary to create icons for each angle.